# requirejs including module that returns an object in another similar module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, amd

I am facing a weird issue in a requirejs/backbonejs application. I have a `Globals.js` file which returns reusable utilities. It looks something like this.

```
define(
['newapp/routers/index', 'newapp/controllers/index', 'newapp/utilities'],
function(Router, Controller, Utilities) {
    return {
        router: new Router({controller: Controller}),
        utilities: Utilities,
        navigate: function(path, opts) {
            this.router.navigate('app/' + path, opts);
        }

    }

})
```

When I require this module in modules that return Backbone Views, it is able to resolve Globals to an object and call methods on it. However, when I try to include it in a module that returns another object, it's resolved to `undefined`.

For example the code below is able to resolve `Globals` to the properties it exposes

```
define(
['marionette', 'templates', 'newapp/globals', 'newapp/views/Loader'],
function(M, T, Globals, mixins){
    "use strict";

    return M.ItemView.extend(
        _.extend({}, mixins, {

            template: T.brandPageInfo,
            events: {
                'click #getProductsForBrands': 'getProductsForBrands',
                'click button[id^="goto__"]': 'actionOnGotoButtons'
            },
            onRender: function() {
                this.flatIconsOnHover();
            },
            getProductsForBrands: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var searchQuery = this.model.get('name');
                Globals.navigate('search?q=' + searchQuery, {trigger: true});
            }
        })
    )
})
```

But the code below gives an error: `Globals` is `undefined`

```
define(
[
    'newapp/collections/Boards', 'newapp/globals'
],
function(
    BoardsCollection, Globals
    ) {
    var boardsList;

    return {
        ensureBoardList: function() {
            var defer = $.Deferred();

            if (!boardsList || (boardsList && !boardsList.length)) {
                boardsList = new BoardsCollection();
                boardsList.fetch({
                    data: {_: (new Date()).getTime()},
                    success: function (boardsListCbData) {
                        boardsList = boardsListCbData;
                        defer.resolve(boardsList);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                defer.resolve(boardsList);
            }

            return defer.done(function (boardsList) {
                //make the boardsList usable for direct UI rendering by any view
                return Globals.utilities.getFormattedBoardsCollection(boardsList);

            });
        }


    }
})
```

How do I make `Globals` accessible in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any circular dependencies e.g.:

- globals depends on `newapp/controllers/index`
- `newapp/controllers/index` depends on the last module you displayed (we'll call it module M)
- module M depends on global

Since each module depends on the other, the only thing RequireJS can do is set one of them to `undefined`to "break the cycle" and get the other modules to load.

As far as I can tell, this is the most probable source of your problem, not the fact that you're returning another object.